# How to add key serializer and value serializer in kafka console producer

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I have below property set in spring boot kafka producer application.yaml

consumer-properties:

```
        key.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
        value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

producer-properties:

```
        key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
        value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

I have to produce message from kafka console producer eg-
`kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server confluent-cp-kafka:9092 --topic TSTTOPIC --producer-property key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer`

but its not working and whn I produce message from console producer I get error in consumer log as below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use colons on the CLI.

If you want to use your property file, then pass `--producer.config` with the `producer.properties` file

Otherwise, you can use `kafka-avro-console-producer` along with `--producer-property key.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer`

As for the Avro serializers, you appear to be missing any `key.schema` or `value.schema` + `schema.registry.url`, which are only properties read by the `kakfa-avro-console-producer` and would explain why your Avro consumer would be unable to read the data (it was sent as plaintext)